# How to use textbox information in multiform application to draw in picture box

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I want to take information provided by a textbox in form2 to draw a circle/rectangle/ellipse/sector in a picturebox in form 1.

These are the requirements for this program

1. The start-up form will have a series of options, as to which shapes you would
   want to draw. The choices will be as follows: circle, rectangle, ellipse, and
   sector.
2. The start-up form will also have a picture box where the shape will be drawn.
3. The start-up form will have an option to change the background color of the
   picture box so that the user can more easily see the shape being drawn (a preset
   list of 3 colors will be sufficient for this option).
4. As you select a shape, a pop-up (modal) form will appear that will get user input
   specific to that shape (e.g. a rectangle would need width and height, whereas a circle would need starting coordinates plus a diameter). The form for each shape will probably need different inputs. The program should check the values being entered by the user to ensure that they are valid, e.g. a length cannot be negative,
   and a radius cannot be a letter instead of a number).
5. Each modal form should allow the user to select a fill color from at least 3 colors
   (your choice!), or no fill at all (in which case, color choice of user dictates line
   color).
6. When the inputs are gathered from the user, the modal form should close (through
   use of "Accept Parameters" button, at which point the shape will be drawn on the
   main screen. ***This is where i am stuck
7. The main screen should also have a Reset button to clear the picture box, and a
   Quit button to exit the program. Also add access keys where possible to your program.

Ive tried using 
Dim Main As New Form1

```
    Form1.Show()
```

But nothing happens when the button is clicked

Public Shared Rlength
    Public Shared RWid
    Public Shared Fill

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text < -1 Or TextBox2.Text < -1 Then

        MsgBox("Length or Width not valid." + "Please Try Again.")

    End If

    Dim Rlength As Integer
    Rlength = TextBox1.Text

    Dim RWid As Integer
    RWid = TextBox2.Text

    Dim Main As New Form1

    Form1.Show()


End Sub
```

When the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: You want to draw picture in Form1?

Comment: Yeah draw a picture in form 1 using information from a text box in form 2

Comment: You need to pass this information to Form1. You can either pass them in constructor of `Form1` for you can have some properties in Form1 which you assign value from TextBoxed before doing `Form1.Show()`

Comment: `Dim Main As New Form1` `Main.Show()`. When the condition defined in the `If` statement (`If TextBox1.Text = (...)`), you may want to `Return` after the Message Box is shown. Also, set `Option Strict On`, then correct the errors that appear.